# EXCEL - find max value in a single row

Tags: excel, max, match

My data is:

| Numbers |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2.3 |
| 3.2, 4.5 |
| 2.3 |
| 3 |
| 1.1,2.2,3.4 |

**What I want to do is get the max value for each row**

My current formula is

```
=MATCH(1000,INDEX(FIND(","&ROW(INDIRECT("1:999"))&",",","&B2&","),0))
```

However that isn't working on the rows with a decimal point.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are these comma separated values in one cell? If so I recommend adding a counter column, creating table out of your data and use power query to split comma separated values by row. Then you can easily use maxifs based on the counter column.

Comment: @P.b  Yes these are comma separated values in one cell. Ideally I would like to use a formula

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure you can use `=MAX` function, just tested in *LibreOffice Calc* and it *worked with floats* as well, should be fine in Excel too

Comment: Nope, unfortunately the =MAX function does not work in this instance

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this is:

```
{=MAX(0+MID(SUBSTITUTE(D3, ",", REPT(" ",255)), 255*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(1+LEN(D3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D3,",","")))))-1)+1,255))}
```

Note the opening { and closing }

- This is an array formula and you don't enter the { or }
- Rather, you commit the formula using Ctrl, Shift and Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data shown in the OP covers all cases, the following does what you want.

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(D3,3))
```

If that doesn't address the question, could you expand your data sample to show examples that fail?